# How to secure SharePoint content

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, security

I can navigate to following path and access SharePoint content easily.

```
\\servername@portno\DavWWWRoot\DocLibraryName
```

How to prevent others from accessing this path?

Answer (score 2):

This permission is managed by the Browse Directories permission level. See http://davidlozzi.com/2012/06/21/read-only-users-cannot-access-sharepoint-via-web-dav/ for an opposite scenario (allowing users to access this path).

Comment: That check box is unchecked only. Noone should able access that path including site owners. what should i do?

Comment: You can access it, but you're an admin I assume? Confirm the users who have access. You can use Check Permissions in SP2010/2013 to confirm their access.

Comment: Yes i checked but still accessible. I added new user to site with read only permission and the Browse Directories option is unchecked. Still that user can access content using WebDev. Is it possible to restrict all users from accessing content using WebDev irrespective of user type (i.e., both admin and normal users).?

Comment: You could walk through each permission level and uncheck the checkbox for each.

Comment: I can't edit Permission Levels for Full control and Limited Access. These permissions are applied to owners.

Comment: This works for me. When i disable WebClient service, i can't access SharePoint site content using WebDav. But i can't open office documents directly from SharePoint site. So i came to the conclusion it is not possible to restrict users from accessing SharePoint data using WebDav and also open office documents from site.